# plotly line chart with zero logarithmic scale

Tags: r, plotly, logarithm

does anyone know how to deal with line charts in log scale where there are zero values in plotly? The lines sort of just disappear.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~SAMPLE_DATE, ~REPORT_RESULT_VALUE,
  "2018-10-04",                 0.05,
  "2019-05-05",                 0.01,
  "2019-10-04",                    0,
  "2020-06-05",                 0.01,
  "2020-09-11",                    0,
  "2021-04-23",                    0,
  "2022-05-08",                 0.06 ) %>% 
  mutate(SAMPLE_DATE = ymd(SAMPLE_DATE))


plot_ly(data = df2) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~SAMPLE_DATE,
            y = ~REPORT_RESULT_VALUE,
            mode = "lines+markers") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Sample date'),
         yaxis = list(title = "Concentration (mg/L)",
                      type = "log"))
```

[image]

I found a similar post in the plotly forum a while ago, but no solution: https://community.plotly.com/t/line-chart-with-zero-in-logarithmic-scale/40084

## -----------------------

An extra example based on Jon Spring's edited answer.

```
df3 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~SAMPLE_DATE, ~REPORT_RESULT_VALUE, ~CHEMICAL_NAME,
  "2018-10-04",                 0.05, "a",
  "2019-05-05",                 0.01, "a",
  "2019-10-04",                    0, "a",
  "2020-06-05",                 0.01, "a",
  "2020-09-11",                    0, "a",
  "2021-04-23",                    0, "a",
  "2022-05-08",                 0.06, "a",
  "2018-10-04",                 95, "b",
  "2019-05-05",                 90, "b",
  "2019-10-04",                    80, "b",
  "2020-06-05",                 91, "b",
  "2020-09-11",                    90, "b",
  "2021-04-23",                    90, "b",
  "2022-05-08",                 96, "b",
  "2018-10-04",                 9.5, "c",
  "2019-05-05",                 9.0, "c",
  "2019-10-04",                    8.0, "c",
  "2020-06-05",                 9.1, "c",
  "2020-09-11",                    9.0, "c",
  "2021-04-23",                    9.0, "c",
  "2022-05-08",                 9.6, "c") %>% 
  mutate(SAMPLE_DATE = ymd(SAMPLE_DATE))

ggplotly(
  ggplot(df3, aes(SAMPLE_DATE, REPORT_RESULT_VALUE, colour = CHEMICAL_NAME)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 0.1),
                       breaks = scales::breaks_pretty(n = 10)) +
    labs(x = 'Sample date', y = "Concentration (mg/L)")
  )
```

Here ideally I would like to have the labels spread out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in ggplot2 using the handy `scales::pseudo_log_trans` function and then using `plotly::ggplotly` to convert to plotly. `pseudo_log_trans` is handy when you want a (mostly) log scale but you want to accommodate zeroes or even negative values.

```
ggplotly(
  ggplot(df2, aes(SAMPLE_DATE, REPORT_RESULT_VALUE)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 0.005),
                     breaks = scales::breaks_pretty(n=10),  # EDIT
                     labels = scales::number_format()) + 
  labs(x = 'Sample date', y = "Concentration (mg/L)")
```

[image]
)

Comment: Thanks. It works for one, but seems to break when there are multiple lines - especially further up the log scale.

Comment: I added the `breaks = scales::breaks_width(0.005)` line to specify more breaks than ggplot2 adds by default, to match the plotly output. I presume if you remove that you will get y axis breaks you'll prefer.

Comment: I edited my answer to use `breaks = scales::breaks_pretty(n=10)` which should be more accommodating of different y ranges, while still providing the right output for the example data.

Comment: Can you describe more about what is breaking and what situation leads to that problem? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I have added some extra detail in the original post. I don't have the data with me but the numbers are representative. I have also edited your code a bit and that helped a lot. Right now it would be good to have labels spread across the log scale better e.g. 0.1, 1, 10, 100.

Comment: Does `scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 0.1), breaks = 10^c(-2:10), labels = scales::number_format()) +` do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Would removing zero work for you?

```r
plot_ly(data = df2 %>% filter(REPORT_RESULT_VALUE > 0)) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~SAMPLE_DATE,
            y = ~REPORT_RESULT_VALUE,
            mode = "lines+markers",
            na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Sample date'),
         yaxis = list(title = "Concentration (mg/L)",
                      type = "log"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. It is a solution, but ideally I would like to have the zero there as the absence of the item is useful as well (even though the values when they are there are small).